# Get table row ID and update specific array value based on ID when clicked.

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a table with each TR given an ID with a letter+numeric value like below:

```
<tr id="a0">
    <td>Content #1</td>
    <td><div id="cs"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr id="a1">
    <td>Content #2</td>
    <td><div id="cs"></div></td>
</tr>
```

I also have an array with the same number of values as there are TRs:

```
var Array = [ 0, 0 ];
```

When the div "cs" is clicked, trying to have it check the table row ID and update a specific value of the array based on that. So for example if the div in TR a0 is clicked, the first array value would be set to 1, if the div in TR a1 is clicked, the second array value would be set to 1.

I know I could go through and make a huge if statement to do this but I was wondering if theres a better way.

Sorry if this is worded horribly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `index` method for getting the index of the clicked element in the cached jQuery collection.

```
var arr = [0, 0];

var $tr = $('tbody tr').on('click', function () {
    var i = $tr.index(this);
    arr[i] = 1;
});
```

As David Thomas mentions in his comment you can also use the `rowIndex` property of the TR DOM Element object instead of the jQuery `index` method.

```
arr[this.rowIndex] = 1;
```

Comment: Other than a temptation to use `rowIndex`, this is how I'd do it.

Comment: @DavidThomas Very good call, indeed. Thanks for mentioning the `rowIndex`.

Comment: I dismissed it, because I couldn't see an easy way of navigating to the `tr` (to access the `rowIndex`) without using `closest()`, at which point you've got a jQuery object, which means invoking either `index()` or `prop('rowIndex')`, and I'm not sure there's a saving to be made. But I didn't see that `this` is the `tr` itself...d'oh! ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas The downside of the `rowIndex` is it also includes the count of the `thead`'s `tr` children, otherwise it's more efficient that using jQuery, however, IMO being obsessed about the performance for simple applications is wasting the time, currently I try to not be pessimist about the performance unless the app doesn't work fast enough, maintainability has the highest priority :)

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwLPf/).

When the page is loaded, the values from the array are associated with each of the tds in the table.

Then to read the data, just click on the td, and the data are read, without any need for labels.

JS

```
var myarray = new Array ('First', 'Second', 'Third');

for( i=0; i < myarray.length; i++ )
   {
    $("table tr:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ") td").data( "Stuff", myarray[i] );
    }

$( "td" ).click(function(){

    alert( $( this ).data( "Stuff") );

});
```

Comment: Well the idea is to have it hide/show the row when clicked (setting the array values to either 1 or 0). The array is converted to a cookie, then when the user returns its converted back to an array and the approproate rows are hidden on page load.